# Строка палиндром

Tags: bash

Возможно ли проверить является ли строка палиндромом в bash в одну строку?

Comment: Вопрос то не обязательно писать в одну строку. Опишите задачу доступно и во всех деталях. Напишите как Вы пытались ее сами решить, что бы другим участникам не пришлось перебирать зря варианты.  Вы ведь не пытаетесь просто получить ответы типа "Да, можно" или "Нет, нельзя...наверное".

Comment: Зачем в одну строку? Создайте алиас короткий, а реализацию напишите как следует ясно и понятно.

Answer (score 3):

да, в принципе, любую программу для интерпретатора *bash* (в реализации от проекта *gnu*) можно при желании записать в одну строку.

например:

```
$ s="Аргентина манит негра!"
$ s1=${s,,};s2=${s1//[^[:alpha:].-]/};s3="";for((i=0;i<${#s2};i++));do s3="$s3${s2:~i:1}";done;[ "$s2" = "$s3" ] && echo "палиндром" || echo "нет"
палиндром
```

Answer (score 2):

Например:

```
(x=$(sed 's/[^[:alpha:]]//g;s/.*/\L&/' <<< 'Аргентина манит всех!');[ "$(rev <<< $x)"="$x" ]&&echo true||echo false)
```

Можно одним `awk`'ом обойтись, все зависит от конечной цели.

Comment: Афроамериканца ))) Пусть и не будет тогда палиндромом фраза, зато правильно )))) За решение +

Comment: а где тут программа bash?

Comment: @aleksandr barakin, наденьте очки. Вы давно у окулиста были? Читайте маны.

Comment: спасибо за подсказку. надел очки. вижу вызов двух программ: sed и rev. и предположение об использовании ещё одной программы — awk. могу, кстати, выдвинуть ещё ряд предположений: python, perl, ruby, tcl, lua и т.п. но где же тут программа bash? ведь именно о ней говорится в вопросе.

Comment: @aleksandr barakin, странные очки у вас, право. Запись в переменную, а также использование test, операторов && и || - вот вам и bash. Если вы не заметили, большинство решений в bash, как и любом другом командном шелле, реализуется за счёт внешних утилит. Для примера, вам поставят задачу найти некий текст в каком-то файле, вы будете реализовать grep на голом bash? Так что не нужно истерик и понтов.

Comment: `awk` != `bash`.

Answer (score 1):

Ну так как не было ограничений на палиндром, то пусть будет кусочек AbAcAbA...

```
echo "Abacaba d abacaba e abacaba d abac aba"|tr -d " "|tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]"|xargs -i sh -c '[ $(rev <<<{}) = {} ]&&echo Ok||echo Bad'
```

Русского языка не дам ;-) ибо tr так и не пофиксили на работу с юникодом. [12 лет прошло](https://www.linux.org.ru/forum/general/2637027)... :-(

Comment: программы tr и xargs — это совсем не программа bash.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin «является ли строка палиндромом в bash в одну строку»
Программа **в** [среде] bash, это совсем не обязательно программа **на** [языке] bash. ;-) И однострочники таки чаще пишут с применением coreutils / findutils, а не растекаются "циклами по древу". ;-)  Ещё скажите что стандартные утилиты, конвейеры, перенаправление вывода и вот это вот всё, вы никогда не используете в своей работе, а всегда пишете на pure bash. Это ведь будет неправдой.